# Can I share our AIAA journal article on ResearchGate?

Tags: publications, journals

This [website](https://www.aiaa.org/publications/books/Publication-Policies) contains information about sharing but it’s not clear for ResearchGate.
Can I share our publication which is published on AIAA journal and costs money for reading?
I understand I can’t share published article but I wonder accepted manuscript.

Comment: Many journals allow posting the accepted manuscript (as in word format) with a full citation to the published version. I am not familiar with AIAA thu.

Comment: I would prefer you to publish your draft in PDF format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the guidelines you linked to](https://www.aiaa.org/publications/books/Publication-Policies), you are allowed to have your manuscript published on your "personal website". I would interpret that term in such an extensive way that I would include your ResearchGate profile, for it serves the same function as a "personal website". That is, it serves to showcase your research.

In addition, [Sherpa/Romeo](https://v2.sherpa.ac.uk/romeo/) (a platform that collects data about journals' Open Access policy) seems to be equally liberal in interpreting the AIAA approach. Pick your specific AIAA journal [here](https://v2.sherpa.ac.uk/id/publisher/82?template=romeo) and read the guidelines. From what I understand, AIAA journals allow for a *Green Open Access* policy without any embargo, meaning that you can publish your manuscript (not the final, accepted one) on your private homepage (including your RG profile) immediately after publication.